# Split sub dict´s in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Well guys, I created a dict, and divided it using the function:

```
listOfDicts = [{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k%10==i} for i in range(10)]
```

From that, I got 10 sublists:

```
listOfDicts[0 a 9]
listOfDict[0]: {0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10, 30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25, 60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40, 90: 45}
```

But what if I want to divide the sublists into equal sizes (in the case size = 3) and add in a single dict:

```
listOfDict[0]: {{0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10}, {30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25}, {60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40}, {90: 45}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an approach like this:

```
chunks = [data[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(data), 100)]
```

Reference: [Split a python list into other "sublists" i.e smaller lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists)

For dictionaries, you can use this approach:

```
d = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3, 'key4': 4, 'key5': 5}
d1 = dict(d.items()[len(d)/2:])
d2 = dict(d.items()[:len(d)/2])
```

Note that you need to adapt to your reality first.

Reference: [Split a dictionary in half?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988351/split-a-dictionary-in-half)

You can convert your dictionary to a list:

```
chunks = [list(data.items())[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(data), 100)]
```

And chunks will looks like this:

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('c', 3), ('d', 4)]]
```

Comment: the method works for list but not for dict, can you help me

Comment: but what if I can't declare the variables that store the parts

Comment: please look at the example in the question