# Cannot divide two dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to divide a dictionary by another dictionary and I cannot find a solution online that works.

Code:

```
def getRatio(price_a, price_b):
    """ Get ratio of price_a and price_b """
    """ ------------- Update this function ------------- """
    """ Also create some unit tests for this function in client_test.py """
    if (price_b == 0):
        # avoid zero division error
        return

    return price_a / price_b
```

Output:

```
line 51, in getRatio
    return price_a / price_b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Comment: What result you are expecting when dividing a dictionary by another dictionary?

Comment: Also why would a `dict` ever be equal to `0`? Did you mean to test for an empty `dict`? Please update your question with some sample input data and corresponding expected outputs.

Comment: if you mean splitting dictionaries, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988351/split-a-dictionary-in-half

Comment: I was given this code. I think it does mean to test for an empty dict. @quamrana

Comment: @saeed I've already checked that. thanks.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I'm expecting a dict which is the result of the division.

Comment: It looks to me that this code is meant to divide one number by another, returning the result or `None` and has nothing to do with a `dict`.

Comment: @quamrana It needs to divide a  dictionary by another dictionary. I.e. [50,100] / [5,10] produces [10, 10]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is self-explanatory: you cannot divide two dictionaries. You can divide certain values of the dictionaries, or certain keys, but not two `dict` instances. The division operation is simply not defined for this data structure, it does not make sense. Check the python dictionary definition [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

‍‍‍‍This will help:

```
def get_ratio(dict1, dict2):
    try:
        return dict1['price'] / dict2['price']
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('You cannot divide anything by zero')

print(get_ratio({'price': 1000}, {'price': 10}))
```

output:

```
100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns the ratios as a dictionary with `A`'s keys. If this is not the desired behavior, please clarify.

The solution using dictionary comprehension:

```
a = {'A':1, 'B':5, 'D':6}
b = {'X':4, 'Y':8, 'Z':4}

{key:val_a/val_b for ((key, val_a), val_b) in zip(a.items(), b.values())}

# Output:
# {'A': 0.25, 'B': 0.625, 'D': 1.5}
```

If you want the ratios as an array without the keys, you can use list comprehension:

```
[val_a/val_b for (val_a, val_b) in zip(a.values(), b.values())]
# Output for example above
# [0.25, 0.625, 1.5]
```

Comment: 1st solution: return {key:val_a/val_b for ((key, val_a), val_b) in zip(price_a.items(), price_b.values())}. It produced this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: 2nd solution: return [val_a/val_b for (val_a, val_b) in zip(price_a.values(), price_b.values())]. Produced identical error.

Comment: But does the sample code I provided work? If it does, your dictionaries are structured in an unusual way. Please clarify the structure of the dictionaries. I assumed:
`price_A={"item_1":price_1, "item_2":price_2, ...}`

Comment: print(price_a) produces the following: {'ABC': {...}, 'DEF': {...}}

Comment: print(price_a.values()) produces: dict_values([{'ABC': {...}, 'DEF': {...}}, {'ABC': {...}, 'DEF': {...}}])

Comment: You should really reconsider your data structures. It seems like the dictionary price_a contains string keys and values that are dictionaries again. And their values are dictionaries again!?

Comment: I screwed up in what I was passing over. I figured it out.

Comment: Happy to hear that :) If the answer resolves your question now, please consider marking it as accepted with the gray check to the left.